# Why do certain characters need to be escaped in this Elixir regular expression?

Tags: regex, erlang, elixir, pcre

My ultimate goal is to write a function in JavaScript which will escape all regex metacharacters in Erlang. Because I want to construct a Mango `$regex` query for CouchDB 2 via my HTML5 application using PouchDB and `pouchdb-find`. I want to perform a search for a substring in a field on the objects in my database, without going to the trouble of setting up `couchdb-lucene` if I can help it and if that tool isn't needed.

In writing this escaping function, I found that Elixir has [already written one](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/regex.ex#L643).

```
{:ok, pattern} = :re.compile(~S"[.^$*+?()\[\]{}\\\|\s#-]", [:unicode])
@escape_pattern pattern

@spec escape(String.t) :: String.t
def escape(string) when is_binary(string) do
  :re.replace(string, @escape_pattern, "\\\\&", [:global, {:return, :binary}])
end
```

I am trying to figure out how to translate this expression to JavaScript, and in that process, I am trying to understand Elixir's and Erlang's regular expression syntax, which I understand to be based off PCRE.

Escaping the `[` and `]` characters makes enough sense, since they are inside a bracketed expression themselves. As does `\`, since it's an escape character.

But why are `\|` and `\s` being escaped?

Comment: If that's standard PCRE, then escaping `|` inside a character set is not necessary. `\s` is a different matter: it includes the whole `\s` set of whitespace characters into the character set you're defining.

Comment: The erlang "re" module says, "The matching algorithms of the library are based on the PCRE library, but not all of the PCRE library is interfaced and some parts of the library go beyond what PCRE offers." I take that to mean Erlang (and therefore Elixir) is not standard PCRE.

Comment: I'm interpreting this differently: in my understanding the matching algorithm uses PCRE, but the exposed API does not map 1:1 with PCRE's API. It's highly unlikely they modified the library. They must have omitted some functionality it exposes (like callouts) while adding some of their own (like regex replacement).

Comment: "But why are \| and \s being escaped?" Do you mean why they're escaped in `@escape_pattern` in the Elixir source or why they're escaped by the function `Regex.escape/1`?

Comment: @Dogbert Why they're escaped in `@escape_pattern`.

Comment: @Jackson Ah, in that case I agree with @LucasTrzesniewski. `|` doesn't need to be escaped (but is allowed to be) and `\s` is for any whitespace character.

Comment: `\s` may represent any whitespace character, but why does any whitespace character need to be escaped in an Elixir regex? That and the `|` reasoning above would constitute an Answer to this question.

Comment: I believe that's because if the Regex has the `x` flag, any unescaped whitespace is ignored, so escaping the space will always have a valid regex not dependent on whether the `x` flag is present or not: `{"a b" =~ ~r/a b/, "a b" =~ ~r/a b/x, "a b" =~ ~r/a\ b/x} #=> {true, false, true}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Lucas Trzesniewski and Dogbert have deduced in the comments, `\|` does not need to be escaped, and `\s` is escaped because if the Regex has the `x` flag, any unescaped whitespace is ignored, so escaping the space will always have a valid regex not dependent on whether the `x` flag is present or not: `{"a b" =~ ~r/a b/, "a b" =~ ~r/a b/x, "a b" =~ ~r/a\ b/x} #=> {true, false, true}`

Here's the escaping function I ended up with:

```
function escapeRegex (string) {
  return string.replace(/([.^$*+?()\[\]{}\\\s#-])/g, '\\$&');
}
```